# When did the daily sacrifices cease being offered in temple?

Tags: history, korban, churban-destruction

The daily sacrifices which were carried out in the temple did they cease after the destruction of the temple(AD70) or they had already ceased well before that.

If they had ceased before the destruction of the temple, when could they have ceased?

Could there be some biblical or historical sources to confirm this?

Comment: Why would they have ceased before the destruction? Why do you specify *well before that* and how long do you mean? Are you referring to the story in the Talmud of the besieged Jews lowering baskets of money and getting lambs during the civil war between Aristobulus and Hyrcanus? What about the reference that Bar Cochva reinstituted sacrifices after he liberated Yerushalayim even though the temple had been destroyed about 60 years before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mishnah in [Taanit 4:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h29.htm) reports that the Jews had five calamities on the [17th of Tammuz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeenth_of_Tammuz), the second was that the *tamid* offering was not brought anymore, and the Temple was eventually destroyed on the [9th of Av](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tisha_B%27Av). On [Taanit 28b](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.28b.11?with=Rashi&lang=bi) the Sages discuss, whether this refers to the First ([587 BCE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(587_BC))) or the Second Temple ([70 CE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE))), and they conclude that it was the Second Temple.

It is further backed by the fact that during the [siege in 63 BCE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(63_BC)) sacrifices were still brought. This episode is described in detail on [Bava Kamma 82b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.82b.16?with=all&lang=bi), where it is told how the supply of the necessary animals was stopped in the besieged Jerusalem. However, as Josephus reports ([Antiquities 14:4](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Antiquities_of_the_Jews/Book_XIV)), after the Romans took the city, Pompeius ordered the Temple to be cleansed, and the service continued.

Whether the sacrifices were later restored during the Bar Kokhba revolt (132-136 CE) or not, see [Menachem Mor's book](https://books.google.it/books?id=T8wJDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA281&ots=7cTJEZnWHS&pg=PA281) (pp. 281-285). For other historical sources you should again consult Josephus among others.

Comment: This answer would be more valuable if it'd include (and cite) what year is referred to.

Comment: @msh210 Though the Hyrcanus-Aristobulus story must have been in [63 BCE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(63_BC))

Comment: I was unclear. Sorry. The question's second paragraph sounds as though it wants to know how long before the destruction the cessation was.

Comment: FTR, information about the history of korbanot from any credible source is within the scope of this site.